# How to report on changes on daily basis between sprint back log for changes in estimation or new work addedd

Tags: azure-devops

We are using VSTS Only and i am trying to figure out how can i report on changes made to Efforts in sprint backlog on daily basis. Burn down chart gives good insight but i want to get into what was changed. Also, i want to know what were if any new items added during the sprint(could be Bug etc).

I am managing fairly(18) large teams that are distributed across continents.
Also for reporting purpose since VSTS is not rolling up the totals from Tasks to Feature & Epic trying to find out what options do I have so that it is automated calculations?

Answer (score 0):

You can use query to make daily report of effort, remaining work etc for the all backlog items or a certain sprint. Also you can send the query result as an email.

[image]

[image]

But for the daily changes, you need to manually compare with the day before.

Answer (score 0):

I have used a spreadsheet connected to team services to load in the data. I then refresh the spreadsheet and analyze the data using pivot tables. For each period of time i want to save a manually I copy the data from the pivot tables for my comparisons. This is not a very clean solution but i have used it and it works.

Something I have not look into at any depth yet is PowerBI connected to team services. This looks like the data warehouse solution for Team Services. It looks promising. Please see - https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/report/powerbi/connect-vso-pbi-vs

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to these steps to achieve your requirement:

1. Build a web app (e.g. Web API) to do with web hook data and store into your database
2. Create Web hooks for Work item created and update of required team projects to send the request to your web app
3. Add logical to build and send report to team members in your web app